# How to print "Hello World" using if else statement

Tags: c

I am preparing for interview, so in internet somewhere I got this:

> What should be the "condition" so that the following code snippet prints
>   ”HelloWorld”?
>
> ```
> if(<condition>)
>   printf ("Hello");
> else
>   printf("World");
> ```

Please help me in this.

Comment: You should really try something yourself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes ofcourse I am trying, when I didnt get answer then only I post a question . And this question I discussed with my friends also . I didnt get ans So I post it. .

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This one is a subtile one, isn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(printf("Hello")<=0)
  printf ("Hello");
else
  printf("World");
```

**OR**

```
if(!!!printf("Hello"))
  printf ("Hello");
else
  printf("World");
```

**How it works:**

On success, `printf` returns the number of characters printed. On failure it returns a negative number. So the else part will be executed after printing "Hello".

Comment: @Mat So the correct expression would be `!!!printf("Hello")`? ;)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: for extra credit, yes :-)

Comment: What printf returns .

Comment: @Raghavendra See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: You do not read documentation? @Raghavendra

Comment: Yes I read it now. . Thanks @alk

Comment: @alk Real programmers never read documentation.

Comment: The expression `!!<some numerical expression>` makes a proper boolean value of any numerical expression, and the extra `!` for the negation of the condition. Personally I wouldn't use it, instead I would have been more explicit and have the condition be e.g. `if (printf(...) == 0)`.